# Eclipse still thinks I have RVM installed, but I don't

Tags: ruby, eclipse, vim, eclim

I'm using Eclim to get auto-completion for Java, Ruby, etc in Vim. It starts an instance of Eclipse. Eclipse still thinks I have RVM installed for some reason (I use rbenv now). Any idea how I should get rid of this configuration problem or work-around this error?

```
2014-06-22 22:43:10,123 INFO  [org.eclim.plugin.jdt.PluginResources] Setting 'JRE_SRC' to '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/src.zip'
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Exception occurred executing command line.
    at org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin.exec(DebugPlugin.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.launching.execution.LocalExecEnvironment.exec(LocalExecEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.launching.ScriptLaunchUtil.runScriptWithInterpreter(ScriptLaunchUtil.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.ruby.internal.launching.RubyGenericInstall$BuiltinsHelper.generateLines(RubyGenericInstall.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.ruby.internal.launching.RubyGenericInstall$BuiltinsHelper.load(RubyGenericInstall.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.ruby.internal.launching.RubyGenericInstall$BuiltinsHelper.getSources(RubyGenericInstall.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.ruby.internal.launching.RubyGenericInstall.getBuiltinModules(RubyGenericInstall.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.BuiltinProjectFragment.isSupported(BuiltinProjectFragment.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.ScriptProject.computeProjectFragments(ScriptProject.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.ScriptProject.computeProjectFragments(ScriptProject.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.ScriptProject.computeProjectFragments(ScriptProject.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.ScriptProject.getAllProjectFragments(ScriptProject.java:2921)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.ScriptProject.getAllProjectFragments(ScriptProject.java:2915)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.core.search.indexing.core.ProjectRequest.run(ProjectRequest.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.core.search.indexing.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.search.processing.JobManager.run(JobManager.java:467)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/ivan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby" (in directory "/var/folders/nh/07hs5mmj0hs7fdq3181dwpbc0000gn/T/dltk60850.tmp/scripts"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin.exec(DebugPlugin.java:871)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:185)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1023)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Have you checked that all of the (sometimes) rvm remnants were removed? E.G. .rvm and all references in .bashrc, .profile, .bash-profile, .zshrc, etc? I would also make sure your project doesn't have an .rvmrc file.

Comment: @Sady yes. There are no remnants, and there is no file named .rvmrc on my hard drive (at least indexed by spotlight:  `mdfind -name .rvmrc`

Comment: Check your project's .buildpath file (eclim created) to see if it is using any external configurations for rvm?

Comment: @Sady yes! It was a .buildpath in an old project folder. I used `locate buildpath | xargs grep rvm` to find it. mdfind couldn't find the .buildpath files, good old locate did.

Comment: Ivanoats, I've added .buildpath solution as the answer to your question. Please mark it as the accepted answer to your question.

Comment: @Sady I had to edit your answer to include the locate solution. It's in the peer review queue.

Comment: Ivanoats, I've clarified my answer to make sure they look in all existing projects. The actual command doesn't contribute to the original issue you proposed, and is probably why your edit was rejected.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't contribute? The root cause of the issue was that there was a rvm setting hiding in a file on my hard drive. I would have never solved it without knowing to look all the build paths possible on my hard drive.

Comment: The locate command, while useful, is not what you asked for in a solution to your original question. The answer that helped you solve your question was to check your buildpath files for remnant rvm configurations, and so that's the answer I posted - though I clarified to check all projects buildpath files. If you'd like, you can post your command solution can be listed as your answer to the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclim uses .buildpath for projects to set configurations. Check to make sure there aren't any remnant rvm / ruby configuration files left in any of your current active/existing projects in Eclipse.

Comment: Just to clarify, I was unable to find *which* buildpath file rvm was hiding in until I executed `locate buildpath | xargs grep rvm`.

Answer (score 1):

Eclim uses `.buildpath` files to set the configuration for each project. There was an old project on my hard drive that had a reference to an rvm ruby in the text of the `.buildpath` file. It can be really hard to track down all old projects without the use of a file find utility such as `locate`. For this particular issue, I used `locate buildpath | xargs grep rvm` to search each buildpath file for the string `rvm`. Because the stack trace does not point to the project or build path file, only by doing this kind of search was I able to resolve the issue.